# Italian Meringue Help - Sticking to Mixer

Tags: sugar, meringue, macarons

I am trying to make Italian Meringue and I using a candy thermometer and following a recipe very closely. However, whenever I pour my sugar into my egg whites the sugar instantly sticks to the side of mixing bowl and then I have little pieces of rock candy floating around my egg whites. What am I doing wrong? Everything I see makes it look so simple and I can't find anyone else encountering this issue. Thanks!

- 115g aged egg whites
- 3g cream of tartar
- 150g granulated sugar
- 1. Beat egg whites and cream of tartar on medium until soft peaks for (~2 min) and reduce speed to low
  2. Add granulated sugar and 57g water to saucepan and heat over medium high. If sugar sticks to side use a wet pastry brush to remove sugar crystals
  3. Cook sugar until it reaches 235 degrees Fahrenheit.
  4. When sugar is 235 degrees quickly and steadily pour it down the side of the mixer bowl while the mixer is on medium speed
  5. Whip for about 4 minutes until glossy

Comment: I added the recipe :)

Comment: So, when you say 'sugar" you're talking about the sugar syrup, right? And it's still hot? Your recipe says to pour it down the side of the mixer bowl but most of the other recipes I see say to pour it into the whites (avoiding the beaters). Is it possible your bowl is too cold?

Comment: Yes - The simple sugar syrup. Not sure how I should heat up the bowl but that might prevent the issue.

Comment: Well, the egg whites shouldn't be cold,... are you taking them straight from the fridge?

Comment: I am getting the egg whites to room temp before I whip them - maybe its just cold in my house. The mixing bowl is stainless steel and I see lots of people using glass bowls.